# Spring boot load properties file inside yaml file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an `application.yml` file that inside calls a properties file

When executing in my IDE (eclipse) I have no problem, but when running the jar in console (with java -jar) it doesn't load the properties file that is set in YAML file.

Here is my `application.yml`:

```
    apache:
  kafka:
    producer:
      properties: kafka-producer-${application.environment}.properties
    consumer:
      properties: kafka-consumer-${application.environment}.properties
```

and here the `.properties`:

```
#
# Apache Kafka Consumer Properties
##
bootstrap.servers=XXXX:9092
group.id=consumers
enable.auto.commit=true
auto.commit.interval.ms=1000
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
session.timeout.ms=300000
request.timeout.ms=305000
```

I'm loading the properties file like this:

```
@Value("${apache.kafka.producer.properties}")
    private String kafkaProducerProperties;

    @Bean
    public KafkaProducer<String, String> eventProducer() {

        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(this.context.getResource("classpath:" + this.kafkaProducerProperties).getInputStream());

            return new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            LOG.error("Error loading Kafka producer properties", exception);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Executing in the IDE, the `this.kafkaProducerProperties` has the right value, while executing the jar is null.

What am I doing wrong and why does it load right in the IDE, but not executing the jar?

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about YAML files/documents. There is nothing in the YAML specification so that it 'inside calls a properties file'. That is all done by the program loading the YAML file. You might as well state: "I have a bunch of UTF-8 characters that inside calls a properties file", makes as little sense as stating that the YAML file does so.

Comment: Maybe the words are not correct, you can change calls for refers, if it sounds better for you. But the problem I think its well explained and you have not make any help with your reply

Comment: The correct words are important. And your problem is not well explained. In the second paragraph you start with `When executing`: executing what? You only introduced a YAML file before that, which is not executable. Right after that you refer to `*the* jar` (emphasis mine). Which jar are you referring to with *the*? Up until then you have not introduced a jar that you could be referring to. So your post starts with gibberish for the uninitiated. I already improved your difficult to understand post by removing the inappropriate tag and taking time explaining why that was needed. Not helping?

Comment: I fixed a multitude of grammar and spelling issues (there might remain some, I am not a native speaker of English). The persisting semantic problems you can improve on yourself, assuming you start caring about posting a quality question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code

```
 @Bean
 public KafkaProducer<String, String> eventProducer() {

    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers","XXXX:9092");
        properties.put("group.id","consumers");
        properties.put("enable.auto.commit","true");
        properties.put("auto.commit.interval.ms","1000");
        properties.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        properties.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        properties.put("session.timeout.ms","300000");
        properties.put("request.timeout.ms","305000");

        return new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
    } catch (final IOException exception) {
        LOG.error("Error loading Kafka producer properties", exception);
    }
    // Avoid return null in your code instead throw an exception
    throw new IllegalAccessException("Error loading Kafka producer properties");
}
```

To avoid hardcoding, you can also do this 
1- Add this in your application.yml

```
bootstrap.servers: XXXX
group.id: consumers
enable.auto.commit: true
auto.commit.interval.ms: 1000
key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
session.timeout.ms: 300000
request.timeout.ms: 305000
```

2- Add this code

```
@Value("${bootstrap.servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;
@Value("${group.id}")
private String groupId;
@Value("${enable.auto.commit}")
private String enableAutoCommit;
@Value("${auto.commit.interval.ms}")
private String autoCommit;
@Value("${key.deserializer}")
private String keyDeserializer;
@Value("${value.deserializer}")
private String valueDeserializer;
@Value("${session.timeout.ms}")
private String sessionTimeout;
@Value("${request.timeout.ms}")
private String requestTimeout;

@Bean
 public KafkaProducer<String, String> eventProducer() {

    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers",bootstrapServers+"9092");
        properties.put("group.id",groupId);
        properties.put("enable.auto.commit",enableAutoCommit);
        properties.put("auto.commit.interval.ms",autoCommit);
        properties.put("key.deserializer",keyDeserializer);
        properties.put("value.deserializer",valueDeserializer);
        properties.put("session.timeout.ms",sessionTimeout);
        properties.put("request.timeout.ms",requestTimeout);

        return new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
    } catch (final IOException exception) {
        LOG.error("Error loading Kafka producer properties", exception);
    }
    // Avoid return null in your code instead throw an exception
    throw new IllegalAccessException("Error loading Kafka producer properties");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Im trying something like this. But still have no clue why I cant refer a properties inside a yaml. I thouhgt yaml was translated like a properties itself when executing

Comment: Ok, have you tried the first code that is the one with hardcoded values?

Comment: Finally I found the problem, I'll poste it. Instead of using this.context.getResource("classpath:" + this.kafkaProducerProperties).getInputStream(), I used new ClassPathResource(this.kafkaConsumerProperties).getInputStream() . Looks like in spring boot applications, the context works somewhow different in context directories, so in the jar it has not to be the properties files in the folder you expect, so using "ClassPathResource" does the found automatically